# Kiel ĉu vi tradukas "tab/tabulation"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Vikipedio proponas "[tabo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabo)" sed ne provizas fonton, sed [revo konsentas](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/tab.html#tab.0o), kvankam PIV ne enhavas ĝin. Oni ankaŭ trovas

- entabeligo (komputeko)
- tabelo (majstro.com)
- tabopaŝo (majstro.com)

Nu, mi preferus derivaĵo de la "spac/" radiko, ĉar oni jam uzas ĝin kun **spaceto**. Ĉu vi konas tielan tradukon?

Answer (score 3):

Fakte ankaŭ Komputeko enhavas la vorton *tabo* kun la angla traduko *tab character*. La vorto ankaŭ troveblas en la [Komputada Leksikono](http://bertilow.com/div/komputada_leksikono/T.html#TABO), kun la anglaj tradukoj "*tab, tabulator, tabulation*". Ĉar la Komputada Leksikono kaj la Komputeko estas la plej fidindaj terminaroj por komputado-rilataj terminoj, mi pensas, ke temas pri bone establita termino. Termino kun *spac/* anstataŭ *tab/* laŭ mi nur kreus konfuzon.

Comment: Kio pri tabspac(et)o? Aŭ tabsigno, se oni uzas *spacsigno* anstataŭ *spaceto* (kiu laŭ mi estas konfuza, ĉar ekzistas plimalpi larĝa da spacaj signoj).

Answer (score -2):

> Nu, mi preferus derivaĵo de la "spac/" radiko, ĉar oni jam uzas ĝin
>   kun spaceto. Ĉu vi konas tielan tradukon?

Laŭ mi la vorto *speceto* estas malgranda spaco. Estas unu komputila spaco. Ekzemple, tabo povas esti kvar komputilaj spacoj.

Comment: Tabo ne estas simple „kvar spacoj“, ĝi estas tute alia signo. Multe da redaktiloj kaj aliaj programoj donas al la uzanto la eblon agordi kiel la tabo  aspektu.